# Найти ближайшие вектора(точки)

Tags: php, python, алгоритм, вектор

Дано n-мерное векторное пространство. В пространстве имеются вектора напр.

```
[ 0.02182626 -0.03014402 -0.06414173 -0.01990378  0.00629869...]
```

Как найти некоторое заданное число ближайших векторов(точек) к выбранному при большом количестве векторов(1кк+) и n>1000.

Банальнейшим решением является перебор расстояний до всех векторов, по формуле расстояния между точками, и нахождение минимального значения. Формула для расстояния между точками в n-мерном пространстве:

```
sqrt((a1 - b1)2 + (a2 - b2)2 + ... + (an - bn)2), где sqrt - квадратный корень, a и b - координаты точек, 2 -ка после скобок- возведение в квадрат
```

Такое решение, вероятно, является медленным. Возможно кто то подскажет решение на одном из указанных языков. Важна, именно, скорость нахождения ближайших соседей.

Есть ли теорема указывающая на путь нахождения ближайших точек быстрее всего(с наименьшими затратами ресурсов)?

Comment: дак вероятно, или медленным?

Comment: можете, наверное, начало координат перенести в искомую точку, и сравнить не длину вектора, а сумму модулей координат. в целом это избавит от возведения в квадрат и вычисления корня, но сомнительно, что это ускорит процесс.

Comment: @teran квадраты, это наверное заданный в условии способ определения близости. Когда вектора [0, 0] и [1, 5], будут считаться более далеким, чем [0, 0] и [3, 3]. Будь расстояние определямо арифметически, можно было просто просуммировать значения точек каждого из векторов и оперировать этими суммами, т.е. O(n + k) вместо О (n * k)

Comment: Квадраты это обобщение Теоремы Пифагора  для n-мерного пространства.  В 2-мерном sqrt((a1 - b1)2 + (a2 - b2)2). Где (a1 - b1) и (a2 - b2) катеты.  Формула (9.7)   https://studopedia.ru/15_74646_norma-vektora-rasstoyanie-mezhdu-vektorami.html

Comment: @MaxU там же дистанция то точки определяется, собственно что у автора в вопросе и написано.

Comment: @teran, неплохая идея с переносом начала координат в искомую точку

Comment: @MaxU в целом без разницы, когда координаты вычитать - при переносе или при вычислении дистанции(ее эквивалента), вычесть то все равно надо, хоть так хоть эдак

Comment: Для сравнения дистанций не нужно извлекать корень, достаточно сравнивать квадраты расстояний. Правда, для многомерного случая это особо не поможет. И для **одноразового** поиска ближайших соседей **конкретной точки** метода быстрее не существует. Если на наборе точек нужно много раз искать - то есть варианты, например, kd-tree, однако здесь вступит в дело т.н. "проклятие размерности"

Comment: @MBo kd-tree - как раз про него читаю. В scipy есть соотв. возможность. Поиск производиться будет много раз и можно размечать как угодно. При таких условиях как быстрее всего найти соседей, скажем, для каждой точки?

Comment: У готовой реализации будет метод вроде closest или nearest

Comment: @ teran @Lecron про сумму модулей координат- узнаем, например расстояние от ноля до 2-х точек [3,4] и [5,1] суммы соотв. 7 и 6, но расстояния sqrt(25) и sqrt(26). Значит метрика суммы значений не соотв. метрике расстояния... Возможно я неправильно понял- поправьте меня пож.

Comment: @Hertz Не соответствует. Для векторов нет понятия ближе-дальше. Они могут быть ближе-дальше, только по неким метрикам. Представьте на плоскости вектора из [0, 0] в точки [3, 4], [-5, 1] и [2, 2]. Первые два близки по величине, но разнятся по направлению, а с последним, наоборот, направление совпадает, а величина различается. Кв.корень из сумм квадратов для 2n пространства, это только величина. Без направления. Для 3n+ пространства, вообще непонятно что. (Почему не кубический из сумм кубов?). Поэтому, с метрикой определяйтесь сами. Сообщество тут помочь не сможет.

Comment: @Lecron Вы переводите в холивар- с таким же успехом можно сказать то же и про "реальное" пространство и 2 точки в нем. Когда говорят расстояние между векторами конечно же имеют ввиду  геометрическое(Евклидово) расстояние между точками с соотв. координатами в Евклидовом пространстве. http://statistica.ru/glossary/general/evklidovo-rasstoyanie/  Справа теплый сверху мягкий- значит [1,1] [теплый и мягкий] ближе к [-1,1] [холодный и мягкий] чем к [-1,-1] [холодный и твердый]- обобщение для условного пространства(для будущих поколений, дабы не считали метрикой дистанции сумму координат)...

Comment: @Hertz Никаких "конечно же". Хотя Евклидово прилично распространено,  существуют и другие метрики. Некоторые, далеко не все, перечислены тут [Кластеризация: алгоритмы k-means и c-means](https://habr.com/post/67078/). Метрика "суммы значений" (Расстояние городских кварталов) из их числа. Как минимум, в первом приближении, позволит отбросить некоторые далекие вектора, чем ускорить обсчет Евклидовых расстояний. Особенно если количество искомых близких векторов, существенно меньше их общего количества.